# How to call previous Android Activity from Unity Activity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, back-button

My main activity has a button which launches UnityActivity. I need to finish the UnityActivity and return to previous activity. When pressing the back button it closes the whole application.

What can I do? Thank you!

**Edit:**

I use the AR player from Qualcomm Augmented Reality (Unity Extension).
I have only one main activity which I start the AR player from Qualcomm Augmented Reality.

**Main Activity**

```
public class Main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void onBtnStartClick(final View v) {
        Intent i= new Intent(this,ArPart.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**AR Player Activity**

```
public class ArPart extends QCARPlayerActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
             finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't getting more clear in this question, but your flow like this way main->unit and if you back from the unit application was closed not back to the main activity.right?

Comment: can you show us your calling activity code and manifest file

Comment: show us the code, where you start the AR player activity.

Answer (score 4):

I found it easiest to use the overridden `onBackPressed()` but to do that you also have to make a change in your Unity project:

```
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Escape)) {

        AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"); 
        AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("currentActivity"); 
        jo.Call ("onBackPressed");
    }
}
```

Then, in your activity class:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    // Handle the activity however you want,
    // what you do here will be executed when the back button is pressed
}
```

Also, remember that for this to work as expected, the UnityPlayer object **cannot** be paused - you should pause it after you've handled the back button press event.

Credit goes to @Frank Nguyen from this thread: [Can't pass back event from Unity to android library jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206615/cant-pass-back-event-from-unity-to-android-library-jar).

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: when you back pressed by default it will finish it

Answer (score 0):

do something like this as follows:

```
 Intent i=new Intent(unityActivity.this,mainActivity.class); // the names of activity as per you program.
    startActivity(i);
finish();
```