# Finish UnityPlayerActivity in android unity project

Tags: android, android-intent, 3d, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am working on unity project and in my project I extend `UnityPlayerActivity` with `PlayScreenActivity`. There are also other activity from which I started the `PlayScreenActivity` so, I want to finish `PlayScreenActivity` after finishing gameplay, but when I call `finish()` method then it close application, it finishes all activities. Please Let me know if anybody knows how to just finish `PlayScreenActivity`.

Comment: You can see the answer here:
[a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080497/how-to-return-from-unity-player-to-previous-running-android-activity)